# Выделить строку Listbox по щелчку по вложенному TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Name="lbFoundData" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NUMBER}" Width="350" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
          <Label Content="ФИО: "/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FIO}" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
          <Label Content="Дата обращения: "/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ENTRY_DATE, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
          <Label Content="Дата рассмотрения заявки: "/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RESULT_DATE, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="2">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=INFO}"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        </DockPanel>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Как сделать чтобы при щелчке по текст в `TextBox` выделялась содержащая его строка `ListBox` - `ListBoxItem`, а то получается что курсор мигает в одном `TextBox`е одной строки, а выделена другая.
`TextBox` нужен для возможности выделения и копирования текста.

Comment: А зачем вам этот мигающий курсор вообще тогда? Уберите все лишние свойства у TextBox (например `IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"`) и радуйтесь жизни, вам же не редактировать...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, убрал "все лишнее" результат не изменился.

Comment: Отличный вопрос на самом деле, надо копать систему фокусировки в WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я написал такой минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" IsReadOnly="True"
                         IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Content="Click me"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Итак, какие у нас могут быть решения?

У всех `UIElement` есть свойство `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, которое

> Получает значение, указывающее, находится ли фокус клавиатуры на элементе или его дочерних элементах визуального дерева. Это свойство зависимостей.

Из этого можно сочинить такое решение:

```
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                ...
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
```

Вполне возможно, что этого вам уже будет достаточно. Но если вам надо сохранять `SelectedItem` при кликах где-то вне `ListBox`, например, вам надо знать текущий выделенный элемент при кликах по кнопкам или пунктам меню, то это вариант вам не подойдет, т. к. он работает и в обратную сторону: при сбросе `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` сбросится и `IsSelected`. Также не подойдет этот вариант и если вы используете `SelectionMode != Single`.

Далее, у всех `UIElement` есть событие `GotFocus`, которое:

> Происходит при получении данным элементом логического фокуса.

Элемент получает логический фокус, когда он сам или один из его дочерних элементов получает клавиатурный фокус, этим можно воспользоваться, например, так:

```
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                ...
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
```

Теперь, при кликах все `ListBox` его текущий элемент сбрасываться не будет. Но если вам нужно использовать какой-то `SelectionMode` отличный от `Single`, то этот вариант вам также не подойдет. В этом случае вам остается только подписаться на событие `GotFocus` и реализовать логику выделения уже в code behind:

```
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                ...
                <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_GotFocus"/>
```

и затем:

```
    private void ListBoxItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ListBoxItem)sender).IsSelected = true;
    }
```

Ну и если вам нужно это поведение более чем в одном месте, то стоит вынести его в отдельные контролы, как [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459885/6766879).

Ответ подготовлен с использованием следующих топиков SO:
[Select ListBoxItem if TextBox in ItemTemplate gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2191922/6766879)
[Selecting a ListBoxItem when its inner ComboBox is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1459786/6766879)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Читал первый топик, но почему то не смог применить к своему случаю.